Incorrect match confidence percentages when using matching rules with OR operators?
In the Duplicate Rules functionality, has anyone see incorrect match confidence percentages when using matching rules that have OR operators?
We have a single matching rule on Person Account:
First Name fuzzy AND Last Name exact AND (PersonEmail exact OR PersonHomePhone exact)

We have a single active duplicate rule on Person Account and it uses the matching rule.
I have two existing Person Accounts

"David Cheng" with email "dcheng@acme.com"

"Dave Cheng" with the same email


In anonymous Apex, I instantiate a person account with "David Cheng" and "dcheng@acme.com", then I run findDuplicates().
Here are the match confidence results

"Dave Cheng" account - 89%
"David Cheng" account - 78%

And yet the system recognizes that FirstName for Dave Cheng is "Different", while FirstName for David Cheng is "Same".
If I change the matching rule to remove the OR clause, so that it is just
First Name fuzzy AND Last Name exact AND PersonEmail exact

Then it works mostly as expected

"David Cheng" account - 100%
"Dave Cheng" account - 100%

I thought fuzzy would reduce the percentage, but at least it is not first in the array.
Has anyone had inaccurate percentages with OR operators in matching rules?  I'm opening a case with SF.

OK, support tells me that the Match Confidence field is known to be inaccurate with OR conditions and that the field will be removed in the future.

"Our Product team suggested that customer should not rely on Match
Confidence to build their own dedupe logic and considering this team
agreed to create a UserStory to remove MatchConfidence field
permanently from the findDuplicate() response to avoid confusion"

